# S3 permission error object lock configuration while just click checkbox the object inside the bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I gave follwoing permission to Group.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:DeleteBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::commonbuckettest/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::commonbuckettest"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is custom generated policy. In that group I have two users. After loging in with one user and go the corrosponding bucket and as sson as just clicked chekbox to one object, it gives follwoing error:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its not an error. You did not allow your users to access object lock information in your policy, so it can't be shown. If you want your users to view object lock info, you can add it to your policy. For example:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:DeleteBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::commonbuckettest/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::commonbuckettest"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowObjectLockConfiguration",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:GetBucketObjectLockConfiguration",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: @MD.AshfaqurRahmanTahashin So other permissions are missing. Do you want to allow your users to access all possible information about objects, or just download them? They can download them without issues.